# puppet: iterate over hash which has array

Tags: puppet

I try to generate nginx config via puppet  . I have hieradata like this

```
profile::candy::virtualhosts:
  abc.example.com:
    listen: '80'
    location: [v1, v2]
    backend_port: [3000, 3001]
```

I can generate server config using this code

```
$virtualhosts.each |$virtualhost, $opts| {

nginx::resource::server { "${virtualhost}":
  listen_port => Stdlib::Port($opts[listen]),
  ssl         => $ssl,
  ssl_cert          => if $ssl { "/etc/nginx/certs/abc.pem" },
  ssl_key           => if $ssl { "/etc/nginx/certs/abc.key" },
  ssl_redirect      => $ssl,
}
}
```

but i want to create location for nginx for that virtualhost  this is code which works manually

```
nginx::resource::location { "/v1" :
  ensure => present,
  ssl             => true,
  ssl_only        => true,
  location => '/v1/',
  server => 'abc.example.com',
  index_files => [],
  proxy               => "http://127.0.0.1:4000/",
  proxy_set_header    => [ 'Upgrade $http_upgrade', "Connection 'upgrade'", 'Host $host' ],
  proxy_http_version  => '1.1',
}
```

not able to understand how can  i iterate over this from hiera values

Comment: Are you looking for `$opts['location'].each`?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my problem used 2 loops outer loop i passed Hash to it and in second loop used each keyword to scan all locations

Also changed my hiera as

```
profile::candy::virtualhosts:
  abc.example.com:
    v1: '3000'
    v2: '3001'
```